# Are our desires driven by destiny?

Tags: free-will, desire

Could there be a possibility that everyone has a destiny pre-written and their desires are just driven by that destiny?  And the concept of free will is just a blindfold with limited options.  No matter which option we choose, we always move one step further in fulfilling our destiny.

In Astrology, it is said that the cosmos have a profound effect upon us.  Astrologers can predict all the major events in someone's life at the time of birth.  While they cannot exactly tell about the destiny, it is still a proof that free-will does not exist.  I understand that Astrology is not accepted as a Science and the impact of cosmos on humans is not quite proven.  But what if we were wrong?  We were wrong about many things in the past.  Earth is not flat after all.

Now, If we find out that this is infact true, then what changes can we expect?
Ex: on "law and order", on "what is good and evil"

Will we still continue to live with the same passion even after knowing that it is all prewritten?

Comment: What sort of mechanism do you propose that destiny takes on human psychology? If you're just asking "is it conceivable that there **exists** such a mechanism", then the answer is 'yes', because clearly you are conceiving of that possibility. But if you want to know whether you can just imagine that something might be the case, without having any more detail about how it might possibly come about, then I'm afraid you're not likely to find an affirmative answer.

Comment: I think that we don't have solid proof on either theories - Freewill or Determinism.  It is just that we feel more comfortable in supporting Freewill.  

I don't have a mechanism in mind on how the theory of determinism will take over. It is just that there is a chance.

Comment: "Astrologers can predict all the major events in someone's life at the time of birth." Citation needed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the question, here?

Certainly there are philosophers who have argued against free will and for determinism.

If determinism holds, and we find out this is true, we can't expect *any* changes, as everything continues to be determined as it was.  Our passion will be the same as it is destined to be, by definition.

Comment: Let me rephrase the question for better clarity.  If determinism holds and we find out that our desires are driven by destiny, then what changes will we make to cope up with that?

I understand your answer but it is hard to think that way.  If I am destined to lead a robinhood life, then it is not fair to judge me by the law made by others.  Even though, by definition, everyone is doing their destined duty!!
Wouldn't there be a revolt on a massive scale against many of the current practices?

Comment: If determinism holds, **no changes are possible**.  If we find out our desires are driven by destiny, are response will be exactly as it was destined to be.  Once you accept determinism, to talk about people's choices is meaningless.

Comment: It's sort of an argument that brings an end to itself.

Answer (score 3):

> Could there be a possibility that everyone has a destiny pre-written and their desires are just driven by that destiny?

It's possible. This statement has the property that it is not falsifiable i.e. it is impossible to prove it false. That's not to say it's true or even remotely likely but no-one can say it is categorically false.

> Astrologers can predict all the major events in someone's life at the time of birth.

No they can't. Or more precisely, they never have. This isn't too surprising as astrology is based on a cosmos that was thoroughly disproved centuries ago. The best they've ever been able to achieve is vague references to things that could apply to a large number of people.

On the plus side, if an astrologer (or anyone else for that matter) was ever to accurately predict major future events it would not only prove your original proposition correct, it would also be the single most newsworthy story since news was invented (probably). So I'm sure we'd notice.

> Earth is not flat after all.

Indeed not. Nor do the constellations revolve around the Earth. Once you know these two things, then the only appropriate response to astrology is "Oops, silly me".

> Will we still continue to live with the same passion

Obviously I can't speak for everyone but I'm going to push the boat out a bit and say, no, many people who do have a passion for life will probably lose it. Again though, as there's absolutely not a shred of evidence for pre-destination, we're good for now.

Answer (score 2):

“Until you make the unconscious conscious, it will direct your life and you will call it fate.” - Carl Jung

There is no destiny. What exists, are your hidden thought processes that you don't know. You only do what you perceive as good, and what you perceive as good  is determined by your thought processes... most of which you don't know.

Once you know them, fate will dissolve into nothingness.

Comment: That old, "Know Thyself" thing.

Answer (score 0):

The question of destiny, free will, and the impact of external forces like astrology on our lives has been a topic of philosophical and religious debate for centuries. Different belief systems and perspectives offer various viewpoints on this matter. Here are a few considerations:

- Determinism vs. Free Will: There are philosophical arguments both for determinism (the idea that events are predetermined and inevitable) and for free will (the idea that individuals have the ability to make choices independently). It's a complex debate, and some philosophers even argue for a form of "compatibilism," suggesting that both determinism and free will can coexist in some way.
- Astrology: While astrology has been practiced for centuries and is considered meaningful by some, it remains a topic of skepticism among many scientists and skeptics. Scientifically, there is no empirical evidence to support the claims made by astrology.
- Impact on Morality: The belief in destiny or predestination can have various implications for one's moral outlook. Some might argue that it could lead to fatalism (the belief that outcomes are predetermined, so effort is futile), while others might contend that it underscores the importance of ethical choices even in a predetermined world.

If it were conclusively proven that destiny is predetermined and free will is an illusion, it could have profound implications for society, morality, and legal systems. Concepts of responsibility, justice, and accountability might need to be reevaluated. However, it's important to note that such a revelation remains highly speculative and is not supported by current scientific understanding.

In practice, many people continue to live with passion and purpose, driven by their desires, ambitions, and values, regardless of their beliefs about destiny or free will. The human experience is shaped by a combination of internal motivations and external influences, and the quest for meaning and fulfillment remains a fundamental aspect of our lives.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Everything and everyone has a destiny, and by destiny, I mean a life to be composed.

A seed is destined to become a tree. The air is destined to sustain us etc. etc.

A tree doesn't choose to be a tree, it was designed to become a tree, so it does as it was designed to do. We are different from say, the trees in the fact that we do in fact have free-will and can chose our fate.

If someone chose to be a smoker and ultimately died of cancer at a young age, they made that choice to smoke. The universe didn't, they did. The choices YOU choose affects your life; your destiny.

When the Bible talks about destiny, it talks about God already knowing what choices YOU will make, so he knows your destiny. He has a plan for your life and has equipped you with what you need to fulfill that pre-destined plan, but God gave us the choice to decide for ourselves to do his plan our compose our own. God knows what is best for us (after all, he knows the future!) and we are always happier when we go down his path, but only you can choose which path you go on.

P.S. Their are only two paths, your path and God's. All throughout history, where we see civilizations rising and falling, I tell you, man began decline when they stated relying on their own wisdom. . . just a thought.

I enjoyed your question here. I know you asked it a LONG time ago but I found it on here and it stuck out to me. I hope what I wrote is helpful to you.

Ava

Comment: I don't follow you. Was the air destined to sustain us before we didn't exist, e.g. 50 million years ago? If not, how and why has it changed? Who decides the destiny of things?

Comment: Since I was putting God into prospective, I meant to convey that it is God who decides the destiny of things.

Comment: God? Which God? There are many. Also, do you have any evidence (analytic, experimental or through references to bibliography) of that?

Comment: This is funny, a friend of mine had just recently recommended me to your blog. It is nice to talk with you. When I said 'God' I was referring to Jesus Christ. I am sorry for not being clear on that. I do have biblical references. However, it is a bit much to type out on here. Can we correspond somewhere else? I would respect your input.

Comment: My blog? Which one? With regard to God, what evidence do you have that Jesus Christ decides the destiny of everything?

Comment: By "explanation and content", we mean philosophical content. I don't see much here.